# How do I split up a year range into individual years in a given field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I was working in Access to make a query of a few tables, and realized that a column of a table does not meet a specific requirement.

I have a field that consists of thousands of records, and it contains "years" in the following format (an example) : `1915-1918`.

What I want to accomplish is to make that value individual in the records. So 
the end result would be : `1915,1916,1917,1918`.

Basically, I want to convert `1915-1918` to `1915,1916,1917,1918`.

I thought a simple concatenation would suffice, but could not wrap my head around how to make it so that it can do it for all thousands of records. I did some research and reached the conclusion that a user defined function might be the way to go. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your field value consists of 4 digits followed by a dash followed by 4 more digits, this function returns a comma-separated list of years.

In any other cases (Null, a single year such as "1915" instead of a year range, or anything else), the function returns the starting value.

```vb
Public Function YearList(ByVal pInput As Variant) As Variant
    Dim astrPieces() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim varReturn As Variant

    If pInput Like "####-####" Then
        astrPieces = Split(pInput, "-")
        lngFirst = CLng(astrPieces(0))
        lngLast = CLng(astrPieces(1))
        For i = lngFirst To lngLast
            varReturn = varReturn & "," & CStr(i)
        Next
        If Len(varReturn) > 0 Then
            varReturn = Mid(varReturn, 2)
        End If
    Else
        varReturn = pInput
    End If
    YearList = varReturn
End Function
```

However, this approach assumes the start year in each range will be less than the end year.  In other words, you would need to invest more effort to make `YearList("1915-1912")` return a list of years instead of an empty string.

If that function returns what you want, you could use it in a `SELECT` query.

```sql
SELECT years_field, YearList(years_field)
FROM YourTable;
```

Or if you want to replace the stored values in your years field, you can use the function in an `UPDATE` query.

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET years_field = YearList(years_field);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I looked over the code to make sure I understand (I want to learn as I go through this). I have a pretty large query, so when calling the function to the query I get a "Undefined function in expression". I looked up possible issues, but none seem to pertain to this issue. I changed the name of the function to "Conversion" because it was called "YearList" and apparently it can't be the same name, but that didn't change anything. Any ideas ? thanks btw

Comment: If you change the name of the function, make sure to change it in both places: `Public Function YearList` and `YearList = varReturn`.  Test your function in the Immediate window: `? Conversion("1915-1918")`  Does it work?

Comment: ok I kept getting compile errors, and I realized the module name and the procedures within them have the same name and they're not supposed to. Once I changed the name of the module, It compiled perfectly in the immediate window. I'll try and implementing into a query now.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. I had to update the Year field because of unnecessary spaces, it would affect the code and not let it function properly. I have a question, It starts a whole new field called "Expr1001", is there a way I can have this replace my Year field in the query, or would I have to use an update query on the field itself ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking now.  Use an `UPDATE` query if you want to alter the stored values.  If this is about the column name in a `SELECT` query, use an alias.  However, that can be tricky when you want to reuse a field name as the alias for a field expression.  And it may be more challenging when the field name is a reserved word such as `Year`.

Comment: Ok, I did an update query as its faster and a much more simple solution, It updates my existing table which then updates the query automatically. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Split` function to return an array from the "years" field that contains the upper and lower year.  Then loop from the lower year to the upper year and build the concatenated string.  For example:

```
Public Function SplitYears(Years As String) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String

    v = Split(Years, "-", 2)
    If UBound(v) = 1 Then
        For i = v(0) To v(1)
            s = s & "," & CStr(i)
        Next i
        s = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
    Else
        s = v(0)
    End If
    SplitYears = s

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, make a sequential reference table of Years, for the range of years that you expect to encounter.

Next, use left and right functions to get the start and end of the range.

Create an update query and update the target field with a concatenation of target field to itself and then also the reference year values between that also fit between the start and end of the range.

Or I guess you could make a user function.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to a module in Visual Basic

```
Public Function CommaDates(Start_End) As String
    Dim strt As String
    Dim endd As String
    Dim x As Long

    strt = Left(Start_End, 4)
    endd = Right(Start_End, 4)
    CommaDates = strt

    For x = strt + 1 To endd
        CommaDates = CommaDates & "," & x
    Next x
End Function
```

Call this in a query like `NEW_DATE: CommaDates([OLD_DATE_FIELD_NAME])`